# Print preview of my web page to pdf and save it on server side programmatically

Tags: pdf, printing, save, preview

I have a deceitfully difficult problem which I had thought it was easy one at the beginning and yet I have spent more than 3 days on and off in total.

what I simply need to do is to save the print preview of the page to PDF file on server side from code behind initiating by a button click.

I was expecting using an open source and then I thought there would be a code like `xyzopencode.savepasgeaspdf(path)` but I could not find it. I got really close to solution by saving the PDF but then I realized it did not save the picture it only saved the strings.

I tried the pdfsharp but as long as I see it draws the whole thing from scratch and I am nor sure if I can do it.

The reason I need picture compatible one is I have 3rd party signature controller on my page and my couple of attempts worked without them or any picture but when I added pictures they failed to show to picture or did not create the PDF at all. The perfect solution would be just saving what ever shows up in the print preview as PDF, just like the built in feature of Google chrome (but on server side).